# XML components overlap in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

XML components overlap in landscape mode.
Hi, I have a drawer layout with menu options in it. The sub-linear layout contains the information of my application. However, when using the device sideways, the constraints layout rises above the menu options. How Can I Solve This?

My Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includingAppBarMain"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/line_bottom_semi_gray"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_flavorName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appVersionName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_flavorName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_flavorName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appBaseVersion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_appVersionName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_appVersionName" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

XML components overlap in landscape mode.

edited :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includingAppBarMain"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start">
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/line_bottom_semi_gray"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_flavorName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appVersionName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_flavorName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_flavorName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_appBaseVersion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_appVersionName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_appVersionName" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Don't put things inside a `<NavigationView>`; it's not meant to act as a generic `ViewGroup`. Instead, make a vertical `<LinearLayout>` the drawer, and put the `<NavigationView>` and `<ConstraintLayout>` both inside that. The `android:layout_gravity="start"` attribute is what marks the drawer, so make sure to move that to the new `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: I added it as a fix, is that what you mean? this didn't work. @MikeM.

Comment: No. The `<ConstraintLayout>` is still inside the `<NavigationView>`. Don't put things inside the `<NavigationView>`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1De0nac-66M3RiZiJkRGk90RVYC9AO89R/view?usp=sharing. You probably don't even really need the `<ConstraintLayout>` there anymore, but you'd have to adjust the paddings and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you so much. It stays fixed the way you throw it, while there is the menu section above, it looks like a piece of paper standing on it. I want it to appear as I scroll at the end of the menu. Is it possible for me to provide this? @MikeM.

Comment: You mean, if the menu is short (compared to height), the `TextView`s should be static at the bottom, but if the menu is long enough to scroll, the `TextView`s should be at the end of the scrolling menu instead? Yeah, I'm sure you could do that, but it would take a more complex setup. I can't think of any quick and simple method off the top of my head, but I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: OK, I've got something that's relatively simple and pretty solid, AFAICT, though I've not done extensive testing. It uses a helper class to place the footer either statically in the drawer container, or as the last scrolling menu item, depending on how things end up measuring. The example's not too big, so I just threw it in a text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dek96fpSSYIbjBNCOnHzNRvU_V0_jLVP/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTX3a.png. There are a few notes in the code and XML. Hope it helps.

Comment: Omgg Thank you so much. This will help me a lot. @MikeM.